# How to find number of bytes taken by python variable

Tags: python

Is there anyway i can know how much bytes taken by particular variable in python. E.g; lets say i have

```
int = 12
print (type(int))
```

it will print

```
<class 'int'>
```

But i wanted to know how many bytes it has taken on memory? is it possible?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can find the functionality you are looking for [here](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) (in `sys.getsizeof` - Python 2.6 and up).

Also: don't shadow the `int` builtin!

```
import sys
myint = 12
print(sys.getsizeof(myint))
```

Comment: is it really giving the size of myint it is returning 14, as far as i know int take 4 bytes, i think its returning the size of whole object, can i just know the size of only "INT"

Comment: From the docs: `getsizeof` calls the object’s `__sizeof__` method and adds an additional garbage collector overhead if the object is managed by the garbage collector.

Comment: itsaboutcode: Do you want to leave the Python realm? What question do you *really* want to answer? If you want 4 as the answer, then `def sizeof(o): return 4`.

Comment: Do you want to figure out whether the Python instance is a 32 or 64 bits one?

Comment: And int is an object.  There is nothing smaller in the python realm that you can get the size of.  If you want the raw machine int, you may have to drop down into C (or Java, or C#, depending on your python).

Comment: Thanks all, basically i am learning python these days and in order to do so i am solving problem set from C++ book. So there was this problem which was asking for this, i know how you can do this in C++ or C but i was looking for it python. Thanks all and now i got what you can do within python.

Comment: If you want to store *many* of int or another C-like datatype, using a minimum of bytes, you can use the `array` class from the array module.

Answer (score 11):

if you want to know size of int, you can use struct

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.calcsize("i")
4
```

otherwise, as others already pointed out, use getsizeof (2.6). there is also a [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/544288/) you can try.

Answer (score 6):

In Python >= 2.6 you can use [sys.getsizeof](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof).

Answer (score 4):

Numpy offers infrastructure to control data size.  Here are examples (py3):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.float32(0)
print(x.nbytes) # 4
a = np.zeros((15, 15), np.int64)
print(a.nbytes) # 15 * 15 * 8 = 1800
```

This is super helpful when trying to submit data to the graphics card with pyopengl, for example.

Comment: This is especially useful if you want to find the underlying representation of a python type, for example: `x = float(0.0); print(np.array(x).nbytes);`

Answer (score 2):

You could also take a look at [Pympler](http://packages.python.org/Pympler/index.html), especially its [asizeof](http://packages.python.org/Pympler/asizeof.html#asizeof) module, which unlike `sys.getsizeof` works with Python >=2.2.

Answer (score 2):

on python command prompt, you can use size of function

```
   $ import python 
    $ import ctypes
    $ ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_int)
```

and read more on it from https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 you can use sys.getsizeof().

```
import sys
myint = 12
print(sys.getsizeof(myint))
```

Answer (score 0):

The best library for that is guppy:

```
import guppy
import inspect 

def get_object_size(obj):
    h = guppy.hpy()
    callers_local_vars = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals.items()

    vname = "Constant"

    for var_name, var_val in callers_local_vars:
        if var_val == obj:
            vname = str(var_name)

    size = str("{0:.2f} GB".format(float(h.iso(obj).domisize) / (1024 * 1024)))

   return str("{}: {}".format(vname, size))
```

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer `sys.getsizeof` is correct.

But looking at your comment about the accepted answer you might want the number of bits a number is occupying in binary. You can use `bit_length`

```
(16).bit_length() # '10000' in binary
>> 5

(4).bit_length() # '100' in binary
>> 3
```